# make cron job from cpanel

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, jobs

Hello I want to run php file to send mail using cron job 
I opened cpanel -> Cron Job -> Select Common Settings
my problem with command

```
curl http://example.com/myfolder/mail.php
```

please I need correct command because I think script not working

Comment: Search sample curl commands on google n try that :)

Comment: command should be along the lines of `php mail.php` you cont want to go through http unless you really have to

Comment: If you visit that link in a browser, does it send the mail? Do you need to pass it any GET or POST parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/filename.php
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
Wget http://example.com/myfolder/mail.php
```

no need to use curl. just use wget command.

Comment: what the different between them ?